# Object causing an undefined error in console

Tags: javascript, ajax, object, undefined, console.log

There wasn't something close enough to this already... at least that my newbie mind could grasp.

I'm just trying to play around creating a global containing object that has methods, and contained within are the instructions to create and use AJAX requests.  I then proceed to create an event listener for a button. I then get the following console output.

```
Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. -This was deleted-.net/:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: globOject is not defined script.js:21
Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. -This was deleted-.net/:1
Exception in onResRdy: TypeError: Cannot read property 'htmlRes' of undefined ContentScript.js:84
```

I'm sure I'm doing a lot wrong here. Let me know what additional info I would need to include to get assistance on this.

```
var globObject = {
sendToServer: function () {
    alert('you got to me at least!');
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.open('POST', 'counterDoc.php', true);
    xhr.send();
},
counterClick: function (counter) {
    alert('you got here!');
    counter += 1;
    this.sendToServer();
}};
var button = document.getElementById('submbut').addEventListener('click',globOject.counterClick(0), true);
```

Comment: typo: `globOject.counterClick(0), true);` should be `globObject.counterClick(0), true);`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a typo.

Comment: Sorry I missed that guys, I'm sad now. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fix the typo I said in comment and also @Bonakid mentioned. `globOject.counterClick(0), true);` should be `globObject.counterClick(0), true);`
2. Do not use `globObject.counterClick(0)` for callback function, use `globObject.counterClick` instead. The first one will get called immediately when `globObject` is defined.
3. Do not use `this.sendToServer();`, use `globObject.sendToServer();` instead. `this` in the `counterClick` method will be `document.getElementById('submbut')` which is a HTML element. Add `console.log(this)` to  `counterClick` and you will see that.

[A working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/uEzap/)

Comment: WoW! the simplest things. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
var button = document.getElementById('submbut').addEventListener('click',globOject.counterClick(0)
```

to

```
var button = document.getElementById('submbut').addEventListener('click',globObject.counterClick(0)
```

theres a typographical error in this part

```
globOject.counterClick(0)
```